# git branches from browser

Tags: git, github

I've just created a git branch using

```
git checkout -b develop
```

But when I browse the project using the browser I don't see it in

```
../my-app/branches
```

Comment: You need to push this branch in order to see it on the browser. You are probably browsing the remote repo, and `develop` is a branch that it does not recognize yet

Comment: Do you mean that you're looking in a `branch` folder as if it was SVN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you call "the browser".

## switch(browser) {

## case your local file browser:

Git is not SVN. You won't see a sub-folder for each branch appear explicitly in your source tree. Nothing there will be visible to a non-Git-aware browser. These details will be hidden in `.git/refs/heads`, and you won't need to dig that up for normal use.

On the command-line, just type `git branch`. If you see `develop` in the list that shows up, the branch exists in the local repository. If a star is shown on the same line, then it's currently checked out.

## case GitK:

If you're talking about the GiTK browser (also labelled as Git GUI), there's a "Branch" menu. Click Branch / Checkout, and see what's there.

## case remote browser:

(such as Gogs, Github, etc.)

On a web app that lets you navigate a remote, typically branches will show in a drop-down menu that, by defaults, is set to `master`. But for your new branch to be visible there, you'll need to have pushed it : `git push -u origin develop`.

## }

I can't recommend enough reading the Git Book. Here's [the chapter that explains branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).